# React: Passing a DOM element instead of id to .play() method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am trying to call the *play()* method: which takes an id of a node, searches it using document.getElementById() and executes the media action.

```
 client.join(null, 'default-channel', null, (uid) =>{
        //Stream object associated with your web cam is initalized
        let localStream = window.AgoraRTC.createStream({
            streamID: uid,
            audio:true,
            video:true,
            screen: false
        })

        //Associates the stream to the client
        localStream.init(() => {

            //Plays the localVideo
            localStream.play('me')
            //Publishes the stream to the channel
            client.publish(localStream, handleFail)
        },handleFail)
    },handleFail)
```

Now, I am trying it to run in React. This chunk is written in componentDidMount() lifecycle method.

Passing the id to play method returns undefined.
Unable to find the passed id?

One work around maybe is to get ref of the div and pass to the play() method but it expects an string which has to be an id of a particular div.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: so, why not get the ref of the element and then use its `id` like `refNode.id`.

Comment: Oh! Yes! This should work.